# How to check anchor tag with element if it has another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

Im new to programming , would like to know how to check an A tag that has element inside

I have this example.

```
<a href="index.html" star='moon' elem='sample_elem' </a>
<a href="index.html" month='element' email='sample elem' </a>
<a href="index.html" star='moon' elem='sample_elem' </a>
```

I wanted to check if each 'a' tag with star element has elem element.

Tried this.

```
if($('a[star]').attr('elem') === undefined){
alert('star has no elem')
}else{
alert('all star has elem')
}
//it gives me 'star has no elem'
```

is it possible ?

note : wanted this to be if else statement.

Comment: very unclear, use real attributes to illustrate or something

Comment: if you wanted to check individual tag else each tag please mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the '>' of `<a>`, so it should be like this:

```
<a href="index.html" star='moon' elem='sample_elem'> </a>
<a href="index.html" month='element' email='sample elem'> </a>
<a href="index.html" star='moon' elem='sample_elem'> </a>
```

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ooi18/ed14jps8/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check if the attribute is present or not. You could do in this way. And close end tag of anchor tag.

```
 <a href="index.html" star='moon' elem='sample_elem'> </a>
 <a href="index.html" month='element' email='sample elem'> </a>
 <a href="index.html" star='moon' elem='sample_elem'> </a>

var attr = $('[star="moon"]').attr('elem');

// For some browsers, `attr` is undefined; for others,
// `attr` is false.  Check for both.
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false && attr) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: if elem =' ' blank still alerting alert('all star has elem') alert message please fix it.

Comment: so you don't want if the attribute has no value. I have updated the answer, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is`to check

```
if($('a').is('[star][elem]')){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OP wants to check if *all* of the anchor elements with the `star` attribute also have the `elem` attribute.

You can use [hasAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute) to check if an element has an
    attribute of a specific name.

You can use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check that
    every element in an array passes a custom test.

```
// get all the anchor elements with the 'star' attribute
const elements = $('a[star]');

// test to see that every one of them has the 'elem' attribute
const result = elements.every((el) => {
    el[0].hasAttribute('elem');
});

// use the result of our test to take some conditional actions
if(result) {
    alert('all star has elem')
} else {
    alert('star has no elem');  
}
```